# MYSQL Group duplicate records by order

Tags: mysql, grouping, records

My question is similiar case with this link
[Grouping records in order (SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958477/grouping-records-in-order-sql)

but it is in sqlite and cant run it in mysql

my records

street  |  time 
-------------------
  ABCD    |  00:00
  ABCD    |  01:15
  FFFF    |  02:00
  GHIJ    |  03:15
  GHIJ    |  05:16
  FFFF    |  05:20
  FFFF    |  05:35
  ABCD    |  05:46

result I expected

street  |  count   |  min_time | max_time 
--------------------------------------------
  ABCD    |     2    |   00:00   |   01:15
  FFFF    |     1    |   02:00   |   02:00
  GHIJ    |     2    |   03:15   |   05:16
  FFFF    |     2    |   05:20   |   05:35
  ABCD    |     1    |   05:46   |   05:46

any help with the query?

avoiding miss understanding, I need this query to run in MYSQL Database.
thanks for the answer.

Comment: This is likely far beyond what you can accomplish in SQLite.  It would be much simpler to write application code to do this, but be aware that you have to impose _some_ order-by (on "time" maybe?) or the database is free to return the rows in random order.

Comment: I believe he's asking about MySQL; the linked to question and answer is about sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

in MySQL you can do it like this and I believe you can do it the same way in sqlite

```
SELECT street, COUNT(*), MIN(time), MAX(time)
FROM table 
GROUP BY street
```

Comment: This doesn't correctly answer the question.  Note that "ABCD" appears twice in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for contiguous rows (based on time) that have the same value in `street`.  This is a pain in SQLite because it supports neither window functions nor variables.  But, you can do this with a trick.  Count the number of times that "street" appears before a given row with a *different* value from the one in the current row.  This provides a constant for each contiguous group of streets.

```
select street, count(*) as count, min(time) as min_time, max(time) as max_time
from (select m.*,
             (select count(*)
              from myrecords m2
              where m2.time < m.time and m2.street <> m.street
             ) as grp
      from myrecords m
     ) m
group by street, grp;
```

Comment: I have tried your query but it seem mysql is not responding.

Comment: How large is your data set?

Comment: @OoRosdiyanto . . . An index on `time, street` *might* help.